# web.xml welcome-file with subfolders

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, web.xml

Assuming I have the following folder structure in a project:

```
webapp
|-admin
|--adminfile1.xhtml
|--adminfile2.xhtml
|-user
|--userfile1.xhtml
|--userfile2.xhtml
|login.xhtml
```

in my web.xml I have this definition for the welcome-file

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

I want the web.xml welcome file to always point at the index.xhtml file, but if I call `http://webappname/admin/` the server tries to call `http://webappname/admin/index.xhtml` instead of `http://webappname/index.xhtml`

so I tried it with a / for the first char, to search in the root folder. The web.xml looks like this:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/login.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

But now it searches for `http://webappname//admin//login.xhtml`

How can I call the file in the root folder? Isn't there a solution for doing this? Do I have to put redirects in every folder to get my result?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK looking for a file `index.xxx` (xxx being a container specific extension, xhtml i your case) is default behavior if just a folder is provided in the url. The welcome file would be used if the user didn't provide any further information than that the application should be accessed.

Thus `http://webappname/` should resolve to the welcome file while `http://webappname/admin/` would resolve to `admin/index.xhtml`.

You could use a global rewriting to redirect the user to the welcome file, either by using an external webserver like Apache with mod_rewrite or an internal url rewriting like the [Tuckey URL Rewriting library](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/).

Btw, since your welcome file is called `login.xhtml`, shouldn't the user always be redirected when she's not logged in?

Comment: Yes, they should. I have a filter to do this

Answer (score -1):

You need to keep `login.html` in `admin` directory also.Since you are requesting admin directory using `http://webappname/admin/` .With this request,server first try to check the specified welcome file in admin directory.

```
 This happen because "welcome-file" is internally implemented to fetch
     from the user requested directory level instead of Web application directory  level.
```

Note:

> A welcome-file value cannot start or end with a slash, and they will be picked in the order they appear in the deployment descriptor